# Increment ProgressBar with Timer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to increment my ProgressBar with a timer.

Timer interval is 2 minutes, so the progressbar should be at 100 when 2 minutes are over.

Timer Tick-Event:

```cs
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value < 100)
            {
                toolStripProgressBar1.Value++;
            }

            string serviceName = textBox1.Text;
            string ipAddress = currentIp.ToString();
            string type = "ovh";
            string virtualMachineName = "s";

            Dictionary<string, object> payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            payload.Add("ipAddress", ipAddress);
            payload.Add("type", type);
            payload.Add("virtualMachineName", virtualMachineName);

            try
            {
                client.PostAsync(
                    String.Format("/dedicated/server/{0}/virtualMac", serviceName),
                    payload
                ).Wait();

                Log(String.Format("Using IP {0} ", ipAddress), 2);
                ipList.Remove(currentIp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex.InnerException.ToString().Contains("A Virtual Mac already exists"))
                {
                    Log("Mac already exists for this IP, continuing.", 1);
                    ipList.Remove(currentIp);
                    Log(String.Format("Removed IP {0} ", currentIp), 2);
                    timer1_Tick(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

            // Reset progressbar, if progressbar is full
            if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;
            }
        }
```

Somehow the progressbar does not change at all.

It works somehow when I set the interval from my timer to 600 though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code.  Show us more surrounding code.  Make sure the Tick() event is actually wired up still.  Some time it gets "lost".  Click on the Timer control, then in the Properties Pane click on the "lightning bolt".  Double check that the method above is listed in the entry for that event.

Comment: I edited my question with the full code.

Comment: "Timer interval is 2 minutes, so the progressbar should be at 100 when 2 minutes are over."  If the Timer interval is two minutes, then it will move up by ONE after two minutes. 
 Wouldn't it take 200 minutes to get to 100% then?  What is your actual value for the `.Interval` property?

Comment: Well that makes sense. I already thought about something like that. My interval is 120000ms - for 2 minutes

Comment: Two minutes in milliseconds is 120,000.  Since the max on your progress bar is 100, you divide by 100 to get an Interval of 1,200.

Comment: Well sure, but if I set the timers Interval to 1200 the timer is not really 2 minutes. I need the timer to be 2 minutes.

Comment: So now there is a lot more code posted than simply a progressbar being filled up in two minutes.  You have TWO different things going on (1) The ProgressBar and (2) Some kind of "payload" code.  Give more details.  Should the "payload" only occur AFTER the two minutes is up?  Is the progressbar tied to the "progress" of the payload?  Does the payload start, and then you want the progressbar to run separately, filling up in two minute intervals?

Comment: The payload thing starts, and runs every 2 minutes. But also IN these 2 minutes the progressbar should fill up, then reset after the 2 minutes and start over.

Comment: _"Timer interval is `2 minutes`, so the progressbar should be at `100 when 2 minutes are over`."_ - **Incorrect**.  After two minutes you will get your **first** tick and your progress bar incremented by **one**.  It won't be full for another 99 ticks or 99 x 2 minutes = 198 minutes!

Comment: I have fixed this by adding a second timer with an Interval of 12000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the progress bar to be full in 2 minutes, so you set the interval of your timer at that value in miliseconds (that is 120000)

But the interval is the interval between ticks, so every 2 minutes, your progress bar will increase by 1. That means your progress bar will be full in 200 minutes, or 3 hours and 20 minutes.

If you want it to work the way you described it, just set the interval to 1200, so that in 2 minutes the progress bar will be full.

EDIT:
I now saw that you tried it with interval 600. Yes, that works, every 600 miliseconds you increment the progress bar value, so it will be full in 100 ticks, after 60000 miliseconds (one minute).

Also, you don't need the first "if" statement. You start at 0, keep incrementing it, and at one point it will be 99. You increment again, and in the same call of the Tick method you check if it reached 100, and reset it. So you always increment, no need for checking :)

ANOTHER EDIT:
To understand what I explained, this is what I meant:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value++;
        
        // Reset progressbar, if progressbar is full
        if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;

            // Do what needs to be done every 2 minutes
            string serviceName = textBox1.Text;
            string ipAddress = currentIp.ToString();
            string type = "ovh";
            string virtualMachineName = "s";

            Dictionary<string, object> payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            payload.Add("ipAddress", ipAddress);
            payload.Add("type", type);
            payload.Add("virtualMachineName", virtualMachineName);

            try
            {
                client.PostAsync(
                    String.Format("/dedicated/server/{0}/virtualMac", serviceName),
                    payload
                ).Wait();

                Log(String.Format("Using IP {0} ", ipAddress), 2);
                ipList.Remove(currentIp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex.InnerException.ToString().Contains("A Virtual Mac already exists"))
                {
                    Log("Mac already exists for this IP, continuing.", 1);
                    ipList.Remove(currentIp);
                    Log(String.Format("Removed IP {0} ", currentIp), 2);
                    timer1_Tick(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well sure, but if I set the timers Interval to 1200 the timer is not really 2 minutes. I need the timer to be 2 minutes.

Comment: for what else do you need the timer to be 2 minutes? For the only code you showed us, you don't need the interval to be 2 minutes.

Comment: thats true. I've left the commented code out because I didnt need it for testing. I edited my question now.

Comment: So what you have between the two if statements is what needs to be done every two minutes. Why not put that code under the second if statement? The progress bar will be finished in every two minutes, and only after that it resets, so it should work as you need it to work.
If you set the timer to interval 1200, of course

Comment: Please let me know if you tried this. I am pretty sure it works, if you set the interval at 1200. It would be nice to also let future visitors of this page know this is a correct answer :)

Comment: Well if I am correct that from your code the main part of my code is starting AFTER the 100% is reached? I actually want the code to be run directly and start the progressbar with it. So if I fire the tick event, right now, I have to wait 2 minutes for the actual code to be run? Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes, you need to wait 2 minutes after the aplication runs, and then the code happens. But this was the case before, you know? the timer does not tick at the start of the aplication, so if your interval vas 120000 before, you were having the same result as now, but the progress bar was not working as expected.

Comment: If you want your code to run at the beginning and at every 2 minutes, I suggest you put all that code in a different method. Call that method at the beginning, on Form_Load or in the constructor after the InitializeComponent() is called, and also call that method when the progress bar is filled. If you want, I can edit my response to illustrate that, but probably tomorrow since I'm going to sleep soon.

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one, but I have fixed this by adding a second timer with an Interval of 12000.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake to tie the event timer interval to the value shown in the progress bar. The event timer interval should depend only on how often you want to refresh the display; the value shown in the progress bar depends on how much progress has actually passed.

For example, if you want a progress bar that reaches 100% after two minutes, you might do something like this:

To store progress:

```
DateTime _startTime;
```

To start the timer:

```
_startTime = DateTime.Now;
timer1.Start();
```

To handle the update:

```
timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //How long have we been running?
    var secondsElapsed = (DateTime.Now - _startTime).TotalSeconds;

    //How close are we to running for two minutes?
    var percentComplete = (int)((float)secondsElapsed / 120F * 100F);
    if (percentComplete > 100) percentComplete = 100;

    //Set the progress bar 
    progressBar.Value = percentComplete;

    //Do other stuff
}
```

This way, the progress bar will be accurate and won't depend on the timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach it.  Make your Timer fire only once per second.  This is how often the ProgressBar will be updated, and also how often we check if two minutes has passed, indicating we should start the payload again.  Record the current time when you start the timer.  Every time the Tick() event fires, subtract the start time from the current time to get a `TimeSpan`.  You can use this to determine if two minutes has passed or not.

Might look something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private DateTime startTime;
    private TimeSpan twoMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // check only once per second
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!timer1.Enabled)
        {                
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            Task.Run(() => {
                PayloadCode();
            });
            timer1.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Timer Started.");
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Timer Stopped.");
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
        if (ts >= twoMinutes)
        {               
            Task.Run(() => {
                PayloadCode();
            });

            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;                
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value = (int)(ts.TotalMilliseconds / twoMinutes.TotalMilliseconds * 100);
        }
    }

    private void PayloadCode()
    {
        // This is running in another thread!
        // Invoke() if you need to update the GUI from here

        // ... payload code ...

    }

}
```